# Matrix and Linear Algebra True or False problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q. True or False: If matrix A is a reduced row-echelon form, then at least one of the entries in each column must be 1.

It comes down to this question.

Can I have the following as Reduced Row-Echelon form?
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0
\end{array}\;\begin{array}{c}\end{array}\right)$$

If that is reduced row echelon form, that is false right?
Please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right....imo at least, as this could depend on definitions.

Comment: Sure, yours is a good counterexample. One could give an example that involves less typing, like the $1\times 1$ zero matrix! Maybe pedagogically better is the $2\times 2$, first row $1\quad0$, second row $0\quad 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another example that answers the question:  $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.